# How to get web application assembly information from console application by reflection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, console-application

I need to get a list of controller/action method names 
of mvc web application 
from a console application. 
So I use reflection to do this. 
I referenced web application's .dll to console application. 
But I can not get web application's assembly information from console application source.

```
var check = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.First(x =>x.ManifestModule.Name == "RedStar.WebApp.dll");
```

throws this exceptipn 'System.InvalidOperationException' 'Sequence contains no matching element'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assemblies are not loaded until they are used - so even though you have referenced the assembly in your project, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` doesn't include it (yet).

You'll have to use `Assembly webapp =`[`Assembly.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh(v=vs.110).aspx)`("RedStar.WebApp")` to explicitly load the assembly.

Note that this way of loading assemblies uses the *assembly name* and not the file name - you can use [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to load a specific file, but this may have some [unwanted side effects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks).